# Store vectors from structure to matrix without a for loop?

Tags: matlab

My issue is fairly simple. I have vectors of the same size in a struct (let's call it `a.f`). Let's say we have 8 structs (8 <1x1 struct>) each containing another structure b which has a vector in it. I'm aware that I can do either this:

```
for i = 1:8
    matrix(i,:) = a(i).f(1:5)
end
```

or

```
for i = 1:8
    matrix{i} = a(i).f(1:5)
end
```

Is there another way to store all these arrays into a matrix, without the need for a for loop?

```
matrix = [a.f];
```

just stores them all as a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) if your vectors are rows, or [`horzcat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) if they are columns.

Example:

```
>> a(1).f = 1:7;
>> a(2).f = 11:17;
>> matrix = vertcat(a.f)
matrix =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
```

Answer (score 2):

how about using `reshape` after `[a.f]` ? for example:

```
 matrix =reshape([a.f],numel(a),[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
matrix = zeros(numel(a),numel(a(1).f)); 
matrix(:) = [a.f];
```